# Is there a better way to write this javascript? They are essentially show/hide functions (in 3 different ways)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still learning javascript, and I'm using three sets of code - but it seems like there could be a better way to write them.

Set one:

```
   $('#C7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo').on('change', function () {
   if (this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x1') {
   $(".under-drawer-bench-1").show();
   } else {
   $(".under-drawer-bench-1").hide();
   }
   });
   
   $('#C7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo').on('change', function () {
   if (this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x2' | this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x3' | this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x4') {
   $(".under-drawer-bench-2").show();
   } else {
   $(".under-drawer-bench-2").hide();
   }
   });
   
   $('#T7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo').on('change', function () {
   if (this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x1') {
   $(".under-drawer-bench-1").show();
   } else {
   $(".under-drawer-bench-1").hide();
   }
   });
   
   $('#T7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo').on('change', function () {
   if (this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x2' | this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x3' | this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x4') {
   $(".under-drawer-bench-2").show();
   } else {
   $(".under-drawer-bench-2").hide();
   }
   });
   
   $('#C11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo').on('change', function () {
   if (this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x1') {
   $(".under-drawer-bench-1").show();
   } else {
   $(".under-drawer-bench-1").hide();
   }
   });

   $('#C11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo').on('change', function () {
   if (this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x2' | this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x3' | this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x4') {
   $(".under-drawer-bench-2").show();
   } else {
   $(".under-drawer-bench-2").hide();
   }
   });
```

Set two:

```
   $('#Size').on('change', function () {
   if (this.value == 'cab-size') {
   $(".cab-size-image").show();
   } else {
   $(".cab-size-image").hide();
   }
   });

   $('#Size').on('change', function () {
   if (this.value == 'double-cab') {
   $(".double-cab-images").show();
   } else {
   $(".double-cab-images").hide();
   }
   });
   
   $('#Size').on('change', function () {
   if (this.value == 'extra-cab') {
   $(".extra-cab-images").show();
   } else {
   $(".extra-cab-images").hide();  
   }
   });
   
   $('#Size').on('change', function () {
   if (this.value == 'single-cab') {
   $(".single-cab-images").show();
   } else {
   $(".single-cab-images").hide();
   }
   });
```

Set three:

```
   $('#Make-Model').on('change', function () {
   if (this.value == 'toyota-landcruiser-70-series') {
   $(".landcruiser-select").show();
   $(".landcruiser-rack-kit").show();
   $(".cab-size-select").hide();
   $(".rack-kit").hide();
   $(".camera-bracket").hide(); 
   } else {
   $(".landcruiser-select").hide();
   $(".landcruiser-rack-kit").hide();
   $(".cab-size-select").show();
   $(".rack-kit").show();
   $(".camera-bracket").show(); 
   }
   });
```

I tried to look for an online automatic compressor but couldn't find anything to help. All three sets look quite repetitive so I'm sure there must be a better way.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Start by indenting your code :p The last example could be handled with multi-selectors or arrays, or with additional class markup to group related things better. The other two only need a single `change` handler. Also be wary of using bit operators (`|`) when you really mean a logical operator (`||`).

Comment: it's depending how your html is to simplify you code. please indent, this is a nightmare to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first set, you need a function that maps "drawer-shelf-combo-x1" to 1 and "drawer-shelf-combo-x2", "drawer-shelf-combo-x3" and "drawer-shelf-combo-x4" to 2.

```js
function mapping(input) {
    const match = /drawer-shelf-combo-x(\d)/.exec(input);
    if (!match) return undefined;
    switch (parseInt(match[1])) {
        case 1: return 1;
        case 2: case 3: case 4: return 2;
        default: return undefined;
    }
}

console.log(mapping("drawer-shelf-combo-x1"));
console.log(mapping("drawer-shelf-combo-x2"));
console.log(mapping("drawer-shelf-combo-x3"));
console.log(mapping("drawer-shelf-combo-x4"));
console.log(mapping("drawer-shelf-combo-x5"));
console.log(mapping("foobar"));
```

That's better, now let's use a loop with all the elements name:

```js
const elems = ["#C7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo", "#T7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo", "#C11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo"];
elems.forEach(elem => {
    $(elem).on('change', function () {
        const result = mapping(this.value);
        if (result === 1) {
            $(".under-drawer-bench-1").show();
        } else {
            $(".under-drawer-bench-1").hide();
        }

        if (result === 2) {
            $(".under-drawer-bench-2").show();
        } else {
            $(".under-drawer-bench-2").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

For the second set, you just need an array:

```js
const values = ["cab-size", "double-cab", "extra-cab", "single-cab"];
$('#Size').on('change', function () {
    values.forEach(value => {
        if (this.value === value) {
            $(`.${value}-images`).show();
        } else {
            $(`.${value}-images`).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

For the third set, you need a object:

```js
const obj = {
    ".landcruiser-select": true,
    ".landcruiser-rack-kit": true,
    ".cab-size-select": false,
    ".rack-kit": false,
    ".camera-bracket": false,
};
$('#Make-Model').on('change', function () {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        const value = this.value === 'toyota-landcruiser-70-series' ? obj[key] : !obj[key]; 
        if (value) $(key).show(); else $(key).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help on this!

Answer (score 0):

### You want automagic behavior for a custom microformat

Let's look at one section of the first pattern:

```js
$('#C7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo').on('change', function () {
  if (this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x1') {
    $(".under-drawer-bench-1").show();
  } else {
    $(".under-drawer-bench-1").hide();
  }
});

$('#C7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo').on('change', function () {
  if (this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x2' | this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x3' | this.value == 'drawer-shelf-combo-x4') {
    $(".under-drawer-bench-2").show();
  } else {
    $(".under-drawer-bench-2").hide();
  }
});
```

I chose this snippet because it looks like the rest is basically a repeat that targets different elements, which suggests to me that you can do this with a single re-usable function that maybe takes some configuration, rather than copy-and-pasting the same snippet each time. So, this is the basic unit of functionality. Now let's refactor it.

A couple of observations:

- both event handlers are attached to the same element
- both handlers listen for the same event
- the only difference is that each handler checks for different values

All of that makes me think this can and should be combined into a single handler. Here's a first stab:

```js
$('#C7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo').on('change', function () {
  switch(this.value) {
    case 'drawer-shelf-combo-x1':
      $('.under-drawer-bench-1').show();
      $('.under-drawer-bench-2').hide();
    break
    
    case 'drawer-shelf-combo-x2':
    case 'drawer-shelf-combo-x3':
    case 'drawer-shelf-combo-x4':
      $('.under-drawer-bench-1').hide();
      $('.under-drawer-bench-2').show();
    break
  }
})
```

Now it's a single handler. You would apply it like this:

```js
function onChangeDrawerShelfCombo() {
  switch(this.value) {
    case 'drawer-shelf-combo-x1':
      $('.under-drawer-bench-1').show();
      $('.under-drawer-bench-2').hide();
    break
    
    case 'drawer-shelf-combo-x2':
    case 'drawer-shelf-combo-x3':
    case 'drawer-shelf-combo-x4':
      $('.under-drawer-bench-1').hide();
      $('.under-drawer-bench-2').show();
    break
  }
}

$('#C7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo').on('change', onChangeDrawerShelfCombo)
$('#T7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo').on('change', onChangeDrawerShelfCombo)
$('#C11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo').on('change', onChangeDrawerShelfCombo)
```

Notably, most of the code is just string values. That info could be extracted from the body and provided some other way. Let's study those values next with the goal in mind of moving the strings out of the function body.

- #C7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo

  - drawer-shelf-combo-x1 -> .under-drawer-bench-1
  - drawer-shelf-combo-x2, drawer-shelf-combo-x3, drawer-shelf-combo-x4 -> .under-drawer-bench-2
- #T7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo

  - ... same as above
- #C11-Drawer-Shelf-Combo

  - ... same as above

Based on this, it looks like you're probably repeating the same HTML for each of these "drawer-shelf combos." The easiest thing will be to hard-code these secondary classes and values. More robust solutions would allow you to provide a data structure that identifies the elements whose visibility should be toggled, and let you map specific values to individual items.

For stuff like this, I like to embed the configuration values in the HTML using `data-` attributes -- that way you can set it up so that the page will automagically add behavior to *any* instance of your drawer-shelf micropattern.

The HTML implied by that might look like this:

```html
<div
  id="C7-Drawer-Shelf-Combo"
  class="Drawer-Shelf-Combo"
  data-shelf1=".under-drawer-bench-1"
  data-shelf2=".under-drawer-bench-2"
  data-shelf3=".under-drawer-bench-2"
  data-shelf4=".under-drawer-bench-2"
>
```

Note that `data-shelf1` is just a more-concise form of `drawer-shelf-combo-x1`. The only part of that value that's unique is the digit at the end. So, we'll assume that these attribute names will follow this pattern:

```
"data-shelf" + unique bit from Drawer-Shelf-Combo value
// e.g.
"data-shelf1" -> "drawer-shelf-combo-x1"
"data-shelf2" -> "drawer-shelf-combo-x2"
"data-shelf_I_LIKE_SODA" -> "drawer-shelf-combo-x_I_LIKE_SODA"
```

And here's a version of the JS that sets up this interaction for *all* drawer-shelves, reading the configuration for each from its HTML. You could put this in a separate JS file.

```js
function onChangeDrawerShelfCombo() {
  /*
    Convert all `data-shelfN="CSS Selector"` into a list of:
    { value: N, element: DOMNode }
  */
  let myShelves = Array.from(this.attributes)
  .filter(({ name }) => name.startsWith('data-shelf'))
  .map(({ name: attrName, value: shelfSelector }) => ({
    // convert attribute names to their values
    value: attrName.replace(/data-shelf/, 'drawer-shelf-combo-x'),
    // get a reference to the actual element
    element: document.querySelector(shelfSelector)
  })
  
  /*
    Set each shelf's visibility to reflect current value
  */
  myShelves.forEach(shelf => {
    if(this.value === shelf.value) shelf.element.show()
    else shelf.element.hide()
  })
}

// finally: attach this behavior to *all* Drawer-Shelf-Combos
$('.Drawer-Shelf-Combo').on('change', onChangeDrawerShelfCombo)
```

---

A few notes for the JS newbie:

1. [Element.attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) is not an array, but an array-like structure. That's why we have to use `Array.from`.
2. The final sample uses [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), for brevity. That's what this is:

```js
({ name }) => name.startsWith('data-shelf')

// is equivalent to
function( thing ) {
  let name = thing.name
  return name.startsWith('data-shelf')
}
```